# Can a billionaire remain unknown legally?

Tags: income-tax, investing, income, privacy

I mean through undisclosed shares or any other financial ways.

Comment: Unknown to whom?

Comment: @BobbyScon to government primarily

Comment: @BobbyScon I know this question looks very dumb but is this undisclosed shares in a company reported to government ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I can't reveal my net worth to prove this because it is possible that I may thereby become a known billionaire instead of an unknown one , but rest assured that such people do exist. It is _income_ that is the key, not the net worth. Too much income and you become known to the IRS; too many shares, no big deal.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This is incorrect if, for example - you hold assets outside of the US [which are recorded in various places now on annual tax filings], or on your death when they form the basis of estate tax, or probably in another instance or two I haven't thought of.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  thanks.. So from all responses I can conclude that to a certain level its possible.

Comment: Can they? Theoretically yes, but there is no evidence anyone has ever succeeded. Speculative questions are generally considered out of scope here.

Comment: @neo if you are asking about something to be known or unknown to some government, the least effort you could do is to tell which exactly government you're talking about. There are hundreds of governments in the world.

Comment: A simple (albeit not too sensible) scenario that does this:  You have a huge tract of land in a foreign country that you are holding for ecological reasons--it produces no income.  You own this land through a trust in a location where trusts are not required to list their owners.  The foreign country sees the land but not the true owner, your country sees the trust but not the land it owns.  Nobody can see the big picture and know you have a billion in land.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to be a low-key billionaire, sure.  Unknown as in not a public figure, of course.  Unknown as in no one including the government has any idea what you're worth, no.

There are tons of private companies and partnerships owned by and invested in by hundred millionaires and billionaires and the companies they own. There will be some paperwork somewhere that this person owns 30% of this company which owns 42% of that company, then through the various tax filings of all the companies, should a forensic accountant or auditor so desire, the net worth of an individual could be closely approximated.  This would not be public information.

Comment: thanks "accountant or auditor so desire" =>forbe's spies.

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be restated as follows:

> Is there any requirement to report an individual's net worth to the IRS if an individual's net worth exceeds one billion dollars?

The answer is *no*. There is no general requirement to report individual net worth.

Comment: This is false in some circumstances - for example, your net worth held in the form of some asset types outside of the US must be reported to the IRS. Also your net worth on death due to estate tax, on renunciation of citizenship, and probably in at least a couple of other scenarios.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: Your comment supposes specific facts not contained in the question. And reporting assets is not the same as reporting net worth. I stand by my answer.

Comment: I will point out that your answer also assumes something - that the OP is even American. And other countries have different requirements to report income and assets, which may in some cases (beyond what I've already described) include a reporting of aggregate net worth.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon He said there is no **general** requirement to report net worth.  Listing specific assets which must be reported does not rebut this.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A US citizen [who must file US tax forms regardless of where s/he lives in the world] living in Canada [who must file Canadian tax forms] would need to report (A) All non-Canadian assets to the Canada Revenue Agency; and (B) All non-US assets to the IRS. Therefore, such a person would have declared everything owned (except personal residences and the like) to 2 governments which share information. Such a person will have shared their entire net worth (or, 90-95% of it).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Huh?  You have to report all **financial** accounts.  You don't have to report real property.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Don't have to report it to whom, the IRS, or the CRA? Because the CRA requires reporting of *all* foreign held assets, if they are not personal use property. See here: http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t1135/t1135-16e.pdf. As I have said from the beginning - there is no conclusive answer without knowing what country we're talking about here - remember the OP hasn't even given a country of reference yet, so this is all conjecture, and therefore inconclusive.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Ok, that varies from country to country--here in the US real property isn't on the list of things to report.

Answer (score -1):

*In theory, yes only from a monetary standpoint.*

You list shares, but anything public, like shares, will make it next to impossible to be a hidden billionaire.

A theoretical way of being a billionaire that no one knows the identify of is if someone held 1 million bitcoins (or an amount of an object of monetary value, like an amount of diamonds) and the price of bitcoin was over $1000, but no one knew who was behind that bitcoin address, nor did the person behind the address use the bitcoins.  One would be a billionaire that no one else would know of ever only if:

- The price of bitcoin (or other monetary object) was high enough in value to make the units of ownership be in the billions.
- The person never used what was owned, as using a bitcoin (or other monetary object) opens the possibility to tracking the identity.  How practical is this, though?  It's not.

None of that is practical though and what's the point?  Plus, the monetary object could crash in value, meaning the billionaire could become a non-billionaire quickly (like Elizabeth Holmes lost most of her net worth after what happened to Theranos).

So it's possible in theory, but it's not very practical.